# Stepline Chart with D3.js with individual lines

Tags: charts, d3.js, linechart

i'm a D3-Beginner and i want to draw a Stepline-Chart. But not as path! I need individual lines so i need a "manually" stepline.
My question is how to draw the vertical lines?

I draw the horizontal lines like this:

```
var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "line");
g.selectAll("line")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d,i) { return x(d[0]);})
.attr("y1", function(d,i) { return y(d[1]);})
.attr("x2", function(d,i) { return x(d[2]);})
.attr("y2", function(d,i) { return y(d[1]);})
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "black")
```

My dataset Looks like (example):

```
[
'2011-01-04T00: 00: 00.000',
6975.35009765625,
'2011-01-03T00: 00: 00.000',
6989.740234375
],
[
'2011-01-05T00: 00: 00.000',
6939.81982421875,
'2011-01-04T00: 00: 00.000',
6975.35009765625
],
```

So:

```
d[0] = actual date
d[1] = actual data
d[2] = previous date
d[3] = previous data
```

And now i try to find out which direction i need to draw the vertical line to next x-value. If the next x-value is higher the line must go up if the next x-value is lower the line must go down.

Could anybody help me please.

Comment: Have you considered using a line generator with a step interpolation? See [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate).

Comment: The interpolation method is only for path elements or not?!

Comment: Yes. What I'm saying is that you can achieve the same effect with a single line (or path) generator instead of drawing all the segments individually.

Comment: I know but i need for every step/tick an individual line because every line will be formated individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it already -- your code needs to be something like

```
.attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d[3]); })
```

You don't need to check whether the line is going up or down as this is implicit in the coordinates.